# jQuery counting effect to formated numbers

Tags: jquery, format, nan

How can I adapt this script to works properly with formated numbers and avoid NaN error?

```js
$('.count').each(function() {
  $(this).prop('Counter', 0).animate({
    Counter: $(this).text()
  }, {
    duration: 2000,
    easing: 'swing',
    step: function(now) {
      $(this).text(Math.ceil(now));
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="count">1,745</span>
```

Comment: I know it's worked without comma but I want the output to be formated.

Comment: Added an answer, with the result having comma. Give a try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove comma from your count i.e. 1,745 becomes 1745. To keep the comma, add `toLocaleString()` to the text:

**EDIT:** Regarding bhansa's comment, the MDN documentation for `Number.prototype.toLocaleString()` can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString).

```js
$('.count').each(function() {
  $(this).prop('Counter', 0).animate({
    Counter: $(this).text()
  }, {
    duration: 2000,
    easing: 'swing',
    step: function(now) {
      $(this).text(Math.ceil(now).toLocaleString());
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="count">1745</span>
```

Comment: It's a good solution, can you also add reference for `toLocaleString()`

Answer (score 1):

How if you remove `,` from string and counter? See the below example.

```js
$('.count').each(function() {
  $(this).prop('Counter', 0).animate({
    Counter: $(this).text().replace(",", '')
  }, {
    duration: 2000,
    easing: 'swing',
    step: function(now) {
      $(this).text(Math.ceil(now));
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="count">1,745</span>
```